# Saving initial ajax loaded contents

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have the following code on load which I am able to load all the info requested into a table form.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$.ajax=({

//all the ajax variables

on success: function (d) {
if (d.success === true) {
    for (var i = 0; i < d.data.length; i++) {
    //div append alot of html in table.
    }
}

});
```

I have also a input search function on top of the table which will **replace** the above table with the search results.

```
$.('#inputid').on('keyup',function() {

//$.ajax base on search values in $('input[name="search"]');

}
```

The problem is when a user backspace all the way and the search becomes empty, currently the entire table of contents will be requested again with the following codes.

```
if $('input[name="search"]').val == '') {

//ajax get everything

}
```

How can I **reuse the initial json data** so I do not have keep requesting for the entire list of information from server?

Comment: this is quite simple,when you are initially loading data put it in a global variable,then if search is empty bind from global var else call service.

Comment: A quick suggestion, why are you sending ajax request each time when user start typing. You can just filter out the data from already requested data by saving it in a variable (JSON object). All you need to do is just filter out the data from that variable. It is also faster than sending request each time.

Comment: sorry i'm not great with javascript, how do i that?

Comment: sorry i'm not great with javascript, how do i that? CUrrently my json returns first name, last name, email, mobile number and what i did was to ajax to my php script which searches through database if the text string matches any of those fields... from 3 characters on wards. So if's like live search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your initial data when first ajax request completed, and after that reuse it:

### Get data and save

```
var initialData;

$.ajax=({
//all the ajax variables
success: function (d) {
if (d.success === true) {
    if (!initialData) initialData = d; // Save data only once
    for (var i = 0; i < d.data.length; i++) {
    //div append alot of html in table.
    }
}
});
```

### Restore

```
if $('input[name="search"]').val == '') {
   for (var i = 0; i < initialData.data.length; i++) {
   //div append alot of html in table.
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much. I'm such a noob but i got this working by saving only the 10 results from the first page and put the rest on pagination. The ajax will allow me to search from the server so I don't have too much overhead on initial page load.